# How do I calculate the required inductance and rating of a common mode choke used as an AC line filter?

Tags: mains

I want to replace a common mode choke (240 VAC line filter) for a vintage computer power supply (Amiga 1200 PSU). The current choke is 47 mH, 2 Ω.

It seems that this footprint is quite hard to find (4 pin, 18 x 15 mm pitch spacing), so I'm considering using a similar 47 mH common mode choke and adapting the footprint (e.g. [SSRH24NH-16470](https://connect.kemet.com:7667/gateway/IntelliData-ComponentDocumentation/1.0/download/specsheet/SSRH24NH-16470)). The fuse on the board is 1 A, so I'm guessing the current choke can handle somewhere over 1 A.

How would this 47 mH inductor have been originally selected? Is the inductance calculated based on the current, voltage, both, or something else?

*Side note:* I appreciate that it's unadvisable to use old PSUs, and many people recommend replacing the PSU with a modern alternative, but I'm attempting to repair it for the purpose of learning.

Comment: Oh! My A1200 PSU failed on me but it was fully epoxy encapsulated and weighed well over a kilogram. Opened it with a hacksaw and found a 50 Hz transformer + post regulation. Ended up with at AT one from a PC. As for original design, it may have been as simple as that particular one was already in some other Commodore design which makes it very easy to keep using.

Comment: I went to a Wurth presentation last year that covered such things. I’ve since forgotten it all! There should be notes on the Wurth site to run you through the calcs. Basically it comes down to how much you need to filter the evil by to achieve compliance. Short of physical damage, cm chokes are pretty reliable - why you need to replace? For the purposes of operation, you can forgo the cm choke. Or just use what you can get your hands on. Why is it in advisable to use old psu’s? I repair plenty of old switchedmode psus.I”ll admit it is easier just to replace them.

Comment: Good to know. Yeah, for now I'll just replace/bypass with jumpers. I believe that a common opinion in retro/vintage computing communities seems to be replace rather than repair when it comes to PSUs (possibly due to lack of knowledge/parts needed for repair).

Comment: You’re considering replacing the choke in the existing power supply, or are you looking for a similar part for a new design? It’s not clear to me. Also, what’s wrong with the original choke?

Comment: I want[ed] to replace the choke, but I was generally curious about how the inductance is calculated. Apparently "They are mostly used to make a device comply with emi and emc regulations." https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/10oz6d8/comment/j6hkse4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Is the footprint something like this? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/253049977937?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20200818143230%26meid%3D94ebf534536941198f87167402129835%26pid%3D101224%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D5%26sd%3D324684606809%26itm%3D253049977937%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DDefaultOrganicWeb&_trksid=p2047675.c101224.m-1 Read this ? https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/design-support/lecture/noise-filters5-4#c8

Comment: What happened to the choke that it needs to be replaced?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I bypassed the fuse, and the line filter exploded. Lesson learned; don't bypass fuses. Turns out 3 of the diodes in the full bridge rectifier had shorted. The result was a bang and a hiss, followed by lots of magic blue smoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMI is a complex topic, so, very roughly speaking:

The biggest source of noise, in a mains-powered isolated SMPS, is the isolation transformer itself.  It is driven at high frequency, and, since it's wound with two (or more) wires, which are conductors, and since there is capacitance between any two adjacent conductors, there is a capacitance between primary and secondary.

So, high frequency voltage is applied across the isolation barrier, delivering some high frequency current between the input and output cables, or input or output and chassis (when one or the other is grounded, or effectively so by bypass capacitors).

This noise current cannot be filtered by simply slapping on bigger and bigger filter capacitors.  That is, a cap from line-to-line, or DC-to-GND.  Indeed we usually have large capacitors in these locations already, for other reasons (some 100s or 1000s of µF at the output, or from ~0.1µF to 100s at the input, depending if we're counting the X1X2 (line-to-line) filter caps, or the main (line frequency filtering) electrolytic cap.  Indeed, the problem exists whether we tie all these lines (in their respective cables) together or not -- which is effectively what the differential mode (DM) caps are doing at high frequencies, so we are right to treat them in this way.

Instead, we must filter between input and output, doing it on the whole cable(s).

Note that, we could use single inductors for the filter, as long as we don't use such a large value that the mains impedance becomes unwieldy (some 100s µH for large supplies, ~mH if smaller).  But they then need to handle the full peak current draw of the supply, which is quickly going to be expensive.  And we only need to filter the common mode, so we use a dual-winding (or more for three-phase industrial applications) part.

The mains currents in the choke balance out (equal and opposite), giving zero net magnetization to the core, avoiding saturation; this allows a very high permeability core to be used, therefore giving a high impedance for relatively few turns of wire.  (Usually the windings are distributed on opposite sides, or in banks, rather than concentric or as twisted pair: the greater distance between them increases leakage inductance, which helps out some with DM filtering.)

As for impedances, the transformer itself will have on the order of 10s to 100s pF.  Often, there is a 'Y type' capacitor in parallel with this (between primary and secondary reference planes), which helps to shunt the bulk of the HF current.  Instead of hundreds, only tens of volts (or ones even) need to be filtered this way.  This voltage is dropped across the CM choke, and usually another 'Y type' capacitor is placed between mains input and earth, or output, to give a return path for the remaining current that flows through the choke.

'Y' caps are usually quite small: a few nF.  They cannot be very large, lest mains leakage currents become unwieldy (typical regulatory limits are below 1mA, which flows from merely 11nF total at 240VAC 60Hz).  They don't really need to be large anyway, because the source (the transformer isolation capacitance) isn't very large itself.

("X" and "Y" types, by the way, are a safety designation: X1 are rated for line-to-line operation, Y1 for line-to-ground operation.  The distinction is, X type must self-heal at nominal mains voltages (which includes surges up to a few kV; mains is a nasty environment!), Y type must not fail shorted.  (Or something like that; I haven't looked at the standard in a while I'm afraid.)  Typically, self-healing film are used for X, ceramic disc for Y.  There is some overlap, and X1/Y2 for example are not uncommon.  The terms are often used colloquially to refer to the capacitors in this positions, i.e. line-to-line in the filter, or line-to-ground.)

So, to achieve the required filtering -- regulatory limits are in the 1mV ballpark, so 60dB+ of attenuation -- we need to use a fairly high impedance CMC, typically some kΩ at the switching frequency and the lower harmonics.

Some rough, hand-waving simulations can be constructed along these lines -- drawing out a typical CM equivalent circuit as above and modeling the impedances -- but beware the results are just that, hand-waving; it's very difficult to construct a meaningful, accurate model anywhere near the full frequency range over which EMC is handled at (<150kHz to >1GHz), as no component is ideal and even PCB traces must be modeled as RLC networks up there.  (For the CMC's part, they typically become capacitance-dominant over a few MHz, but still offer usefully high impedance out to 10-30MHz or more.)

Evidently, your power supply needed quite a lot more than usual, perhaps due to a low switching frequency (as was the style at the time, partly by component limitations; BJTs were overall more suitable than MOSFETs, but were rather slow), perhaps due to details of transformer construction, or other factors.

It may also simply not be a very well optimized part.  Often, systems are designed and prototyped, and then the design engineers (or for that matter, technicians even!) see it through EMC testing -- none of whom may have very much experience in the field, so it ends up a frustrating rushed week (at least!) of on-site work in the test lab, trying everything to get it to pass.  Eventually a passing configuration is found, and that's simply the model that goes into production, no further optimization possible (not without additional expensive weeks of testing, that is).

As for replacement -- try to match the general part design as well.  Toroidal, E-core, etc.; banked or sectional windings; similar overall size, DC resistance (say, within +20/-50%), inductance, and if you can find datasheets, try to get a similar impedance curve as well.  Footprint isn't so critical: pins can always be bent and cut, holes drilled (clearance allowing, of course!), leads extended, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Accurate numerical results would take a SPICE model of the LISN used in compliance testing, the choke itself, and a model of the interfering currents and voltages emanating from the circuitry downstream from the choke.

Alternatively, one uses the approximate knowledge of the interference spectrum produced by the supply and the load. Then, the choke is found not by inductance, but by the suppression vs frequency graph in the datasheet. It’s not exact but usually provides a part number close to what’s needed.

Most loads are too complex to select a choke based just on frequencies of interest.